# Highlight a value in Column B based on Value in a selected cell in Column A (Excel VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I want to highlight, in Excel, a value in column B based on the same value in Column A.

As soon as I select cell A2 the same values in B1 and B3 are highlighted with a color.

When I select A3 the same value in B4 is highlighted with a color. The previous highlighted cells B1 and B3 do not have a color anymore.

I’ve tried to do this based on Worksheet_Selection_Change but I can’t figure out how this will work.

Example:

- Cell A1 = 50         B1 = 100
- Cell A2 = 100        B2 = 80
- Cell A3 = 120        B3 = 100
- Cell A4 = 20         B4 = 120

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you thinking of something like this?

If the amount of data in column B is very large, it might be more efficient using a different method, but I believe this should work fine for a small worksheet.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim r As Range, c As Range
    
    If Target.Rows.Count = 1 And Target.Columns.Count = 1 Then
        Set r = Me.Range("B1:B" & Me.Range("B" & Me.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        
        r.Interior.Color = xlNone
        
        For Each c In r
            If c = Target Then
                c.Interior.Color = vbGreen
            End If
        Next c
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much, it does the basic thing which is great. One more thing I would like to realize. The Worksheet_SelectionChange event should only be triggered as long as I'm moving from one cell to the other in column A or Range(A1:A1000). In all other cases the event should not be triggered.

Comment: @KeesRitmeester Add another if-clause with something like `if not intersect(me.columns(1), target) is nothing then`... If my answer solved your issue, it would be nice if you marked it as a solution.